# Adding a row at the begining of every day of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add a row at the begining of every day of a datetime indexed dataframe.

Example:

```
date  = ['2015-02-03 23:00:00','2015-02-03 23:30:00','2015-02-04 00:00:00','2015-02-04 00:30:00','2015-02-04 01:00:00','2015-02-04 01:30:00','2015-02-04 02:00:00','2015-02-04 02:30:00','2015-02-04 03:00:00','2015-02-04 03:30:00','2015-02-04 04:00:00','2015-02-04 04:30:00','2015-02-04 05:00:00','2015-02-04 05:30:00','2015-02-04 06:00:00','2015-02-04 06:30:00','2015-02-04 07:00:00','2015-02-04 07:30:00','2015-02-04 08:00:00','2015-02-04 08:30:00','2015-02-04 09:00:00','2015-02-04 09:30:00','2015-02-04 10:00:00','2015-02-04 10:30:00','2015-02-04 11:00:00','2015-02-04 11:30:00','2015-02-04 12:00:00','2015-02-04 12:30:00','2015-02-04 13:00:00','2015-02-04 13:30:00','2015-02-04 14:00:00','2015-02-04 14:30:00','2015-02-04 15:00:00','2015-02-04 15:30:00','2015-02-04 16:00:00','2015-02-04 16:30:00','2015-02-04 17:00:00','2015-02-04 17:30:00','2015-02-04 18:00:00','2015-02-04 18:30:00','2015-02-04 19:00:00','2015-02-04 19:30:00','2015-02-04 20:00:00','2015-02-04 20:30:00','2015-02-04 21:00:00','2015-02-04 21:30:00','2015-02-04 22:00:00','2015-02-04 22:30:00','2015-02-04 23:00:00','2015-02-04 23:30:00']

value = [33.24  , 31.71  , 34.39  , 34.49  , 34.67  , 34.46  , 34.59  , 34.83  , 35.78  , 33.03  , 35.49  , 33.79  , 36.12  , 37.09  , 39.54  , 41.19  , 45.99  , 50.23  , 46.72  , 47.47  , 48.46  , 48.38  , 48.40  , 48.13  , 38.35  , 38.19  , 38.12  , 38.05  , 38.06  , 37.83  , 37.49  , 37.41 , 41.84  , 42.26 , 44.09  , 48.85  , 50.07 , 50.94  , 51.09  , 50.60  , 47.39  , 45.57  , 45.03  , 44.98  , 41.32  , 40.37  , 41.12  , 39.33  , 35.38  , 33.44  ]
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':value,'index':date})
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['index'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
df.drop(['index'],axis=1,inplace=True)
print(df)   



                     value
index                     
2015-02-03 23:00:00  33.24
2015-02-03 23:30:00  31.71
2015-02-04 00:00:00  34.39
2015-02-04 00:30:00  34.49
2015-02-04 01:00:00  34.67
2015-02-04 01:30:00  34.46
```

Expected result:

```
                     value
index       
2015-02-03 23:00:00  10              
2015-02-03 23:00:00  33.24
2015-02-03 23:30:00  31.71
2015-02-04 00:00:00  10
2015-02-04 00:00:00  34.39
2015-02-04 00:30:00  34.49
2015-02-04 01:00:00  34.67
2015-02-04 01:30:00  34.46
```

How can I do that efficiently? in this example I added the value 10 at the begining of each day.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
s=df.groupby(df.index.date).first()
s.iloc[:,0]=10
s.index=pd.to_datetime(s.index,format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df=pd.concat([df,s]).sort_index()
```